# Mail count in O365 Inbox using shell script

Tags: shell, office365, imap

I need to write shell script to get the INBOX folder count in Office 365 using below script.

```
{
echo "01 login ${IMAP_USER} ${IMAP_PASSWD}"

sleep 2

echo "03 STATUS INBOX MESSAGES"

sleep 2

echo "19 logout"

} | telnet outlook.office365.com 993 | tee ${LOG_DIR}/imap_status.log*
```

I am getting only below message in log file.

```
Trying 52.97.137.194...
Connected to outlook.office365.com (52.97.137.194).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

It is unable to login to mailbox using imap username & password. 
Since it is O365, i gave complete mail id in username field.

I  tested telnet command separately and that is also showing the same message. Before Office 365 migration, i was able to connect & login mailbox using telnet.

Do I need to perform any specific changes for Office 365?

Comment: telnet doesn't speak SSL.  You will need a different tool for that.

Comment: Telnet is also notorious for discarding stdin until the connection is estabilished. If you want to pipe into stdin you have to add an initial sleep. Which, in this case, will likely provoke a syntax error.

Comment: A nice alternative to telnet for trying to do SSL-wrapped connections is `openssl s_client -host outlook.office365.com -port 993`

Comment: openssl command helps to connect mailbox. I am getting the message as " * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready". After connection established, how to get INBOX mail count in openssl command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you wish to do in the mailbox, you might be able to use the [Office 365 Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

The graph uses simple http rest calls and allows you to do a lot of things on a users Office 365 account as rest commands (POST / GET / DELETE).

You can browse the categories such as Outlook Mail (which is the Office 365 Exchange e-mail) and see if you might be able to work in your functionality like that.

Another option would be PowerShell using the Exchange Online modules.
[Get-MailboxFolderStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailboxfolderstatistics?view=exchange-ps) might get all you need in regards to folders.

If you login with a user account you can only view data from that user.
Using an Exchange Administrator account you can get the info from all users.